# How to get text from the first column in a table?

Tags: jquery, selector

There is a table in a webpage (in my case, http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) and I want to obtain all the method names in 
Stable APIs. So I want to get an array, the elements of which are the things in the first column.

How to do it?

```
$("table:eq(5) tr td:eq(0)")
```

this code does not work, because it does not get text from all the first td elements in all rows, but only in one row. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:first-child` selector (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp), it'll select the first table cell for each row.

Answer (score 5):

you can try

```
$(table).find('td:first').text() //can you table id or class
```

can iterate in a loop for all rows to get first cell value

```
 var array = new Array();

$('table tr').each(function () {
    var firstCell = $(this).find('td').first();
    array.push($firstCell.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [];

jQuery('table tr').each(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $firstCell = $row.find('td:first');
    array.push($firstCell.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var a = new Array();

$("table:eq(5) tr td:first-child").each(
    function(){
        a.push($(this).text())
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the table rows like this:

```
$("#tableId > tbody > tr").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find("td:first").text();
    console.log("Method name: "+name);
});
```

You can initialize an array globally and save in that array in loop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a selector of the first td.

```
$('#package_list_table tr td:first-child')
```